# JVector Map Pulsating Marker

Tags: javascript, css, jvectormap

I want to create a custom marker on a JVector Map. My idea is to use CSS3 to show a simple red pulsating ring.

So far i have only been able to obtain this using

```
onMarkerLabelShow: function(event, label, code) {
 label.html("<div class='pulse'></div>");                
},
```

which is not right as I have to hover over the marker for this to work. It will not work all the time. Any ideas on how I can implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I did not manage to find the circle inside the SVG so what I did was i went into the jvector core and found this line:

```
this.shape.addClass('jvectormap-marker jvectormap-element');
```

and added my animation classes as so:

```
this.shape.addClass('jvectormap-marker jvectormap-element animated flash');
```

Comment: Very great Thanks!! I tryed to add css directly to "circle" and it`s work not like I want.